# No idea what this means!

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence, relative-clauses

Could someone arrange this sentence in a form so that I can understand it?

- This in turn limits the applications in which they may be used to those where relatively non-thermally critical structural parts are required.

The context is about some polymers and this paragraph is talking about the disadvantages of them.

Comment: _Going on from there, this means we can only use 'them' in applications not needing 'heat-resistant' 'main girders'._ (Note that I'm paraphrasing wildly.)

Comment: Rephrased thus could make the meaning clearer-- "This in turn limits their (polymers') applications to areas where relatively non-thermal critical structural parts are required."

Comment: "These polymers can only be used when heat is not an issue."

Comment: @RegDwigнt Or, at least, of relatively little importance.

Answer (score 1):

To rephrase:

Some applications fit this description: "relatively non-thermally critical structural parts are required.".  That is, they require "relatively non-thermally critical structural parts", which means "structural parts" which are "relatively non-thermally critical", which at a guess would mean that the structural parts function well over a relatively wide range of temperatures.

The things referred to as "they" (the polymers) are limited to these applications, because of the thing referred to as "this" (something to do with a variation in temperature perhaps).

The whole thing could perhaps be rephrased as "You can only use these polymers in situations where the temperature isn't going to vary widely".

Does that help?

Comment: "non-thermally critical structural parts " doesn't seem to make much sense; It should be "non-thermal critical structural parts"-- critical structural parts that are non-thermal in nature. Don't you think so?  " non-thermally critical" qualifies "critical", implying "critical under non-thermal conditions only". I don't think that's what the writer had in mind.

Comment: No, i think it does make sense, I think you've parsed the phrase incorrectly.  "Thermally critical" could mean "depends on the right temperature", probably most commonly in the sense that it will break if it gets too hot.  Google the term "thermally critical", you'll see loads of results from engineering sites.

Comment: Ah, I thought "critical" meant "Indispensable" here and the phrase "non-thermal critical structural" as a bunch of adjectives strung together, and modifying "parts". I see your point. You have interpreted " critical " differently (and perhaps rightly).

Comment: @Stockfish it's "critical" as in "critically injured" or "the patient is in a critical condition".

Comment: Yeah, I got that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is likely to be ...

They may only be used where, in comparison to other parts that must remain stable and safe when hot, their susceptibility to heat does not matter.

In this suggestion I have retained the proper meaning of “relative” (some sort of comparison) and have not taken it to mean “rather” or “quite”. This point has been ignored in all comments and other answers.

The obscurity of the original is such that I would not employ the writer to make a user manual or a safety guide!

Answer (score 0):

The original sentence:

> This in turn limits the applications in which they may be used to those where relatively non-thermally critical structural parts are required.

A restructured version of the sentence:

> This in turn limits their use to applications that require structural parts that are relatively non-thermally critical.

---

The use of *relatively non-thermally critical* is ambiguous on several levels, and open to a range of interpretations. Without further context, it's not possible to know exactly what it's trying to say. Either it makes sense within that further context, or it's a poor choice of words.